# Matplotlib: Overplot a line above another axes panel

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, data-visualization

There are two axes panels, with a small one (in gray color) inside a big one (white color).

With the following code, I am expecting the blue line to be on top of the gray small axes panel, because the blue line is set to have a ridiculously high `zorder`.  But it turns out not to be the case.

Changing the `zorder` of the patch of the small panel has no effect.

If I set the background of the small panel to be transparent (or make it invisible), then the blue line will appear unblocked, but this solution is not satisfactory, because there may be situations in which **IT IS REQUIRED** to keep the background of the small panel to be opaque.

Or maybe such a requirement is not achievable in a simple way, if by implementation the `zorder` of lines are only meaningful within the same axes?

```
f = figure()

ax1 = f.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8], zorder=1)
ax2 = f.add_axes([0.3,0.2,0.5,0.4], zorder=2)
ax2.patch.set_facecolor('gray')
ax2.patch.set_zorder(-9999999)
ax1.plot([0,1], [0,1], zorder=99999999, color='blue')
ax2.plot([0,1], [0,3], zorder=-99999, color='red')

# New Edit:
# To make the problem more to the point, what if someone
# also wants the background of the big panel to be green
# (with the following command)?  See the second figure.
ax1.patch.set_facecolor('green')
# This seems to mean that the small panel really has to
# somehow "insert" into the z-space between the big panel
# and the blue line.
```

[image: Figure generated by the following code]
[image: New image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that (if the zorder is reversed from your example) then the "opaque" white background from your first (larger) axes is overlapping the second (smaller) axes, so one way is to simply set the face color of the larger axes to transparent. Also be sure to set the face color of the entire figure to white...

```
f.set_facecolor('white')

ax2 = f.add_axes([0.3,0.2,0.5,0.4], zorder=1)
ax2.patch.set_facecolor('gray')
ax2.plot([0,1], [0,3], color='red')

ax1 = f.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8], zorder=2)
ax1.plot([0,1], [0,1], color='blue')
ax1.patch.set_alpha(0.0)#make background transparent
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is a very clever solution!  And I agree with you that it is still not ideal, especially when a picky person wants to set the background color of the large panel to some non-white (green, for example) color.

Comment: edited previous post. this should get you up and running.

Comment: Yes, your solution works, though when the big panel is required to be green, the the facecolor of the figure will make the whole figure green, not just the panel.

Comment: Ah, indeed it does! Sorry bout that.

Answer (score 2):

I think we just have to compromise, so the solution I come up with is to add a third layer of axes, which is transparent and it is the one who really draws the blue line.

Of course, we need to further fine-tune the first layer (`ax1`) a bit to suppress redundant elements (for example, by default `ax1` also has axes labels and ticks; they are just hidden below).

```
f = figure()

ax1 = f.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8], zorder=0)
ax1.patch.set_facecolor('green')

ax2 = f.add_axes([0.3,0.2,0.5,0.4], zorder=1)
ax2.patch.set_facecolor('gray')

ax2.plot([0,1], [0,3], color='red')

ax3 = f.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8], zorder=2)
ax3.patch.set_alpha(0)
ax3.plot([0,1], [0,1], color='blue')
```

[image]